# How can I host my backend flask app on heroku?

Tags: postgresql, flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a reach app acting as the frontend and a flask app acting as the backend.

I hosted the frontend on heroku. The problem is with the backend.

When ever I deploy it on heroku it builds fine but I always get The below.

[image]

when I check the logs, I see the below.

[image]

I'm not sure what the issue is but I am thinking its in models file.

```
database_path = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

db = SQLAlchemy()
def setup_db(app, database_path=database_path):

if database_path.startswith("postgres://"):
   database_path = database_path.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_path

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_path)

if not database_exists(engine.url):
  create_database(engine.url)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db.app = app
db.init_app(app)
db.create_all()
```

Any ideas?

if I didnt include enough information I apologize, I am brand new to running my web pages outside of my local machine.

EDIT:

I created procfile and added

```
web: gunicorn flaskr:app
```

new log is

[image]

my app structure is

[image]

Comment: The error is that heroku can’t find the module “wsgi” (first line). Is this module in your requirements.txt?

Answer (score -1):

### First Try this in while deploying

`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`

### If that doesn't fix it, try the below

It looks from the logs that you have not configured the dynamo properly in your Procfile. Use gunicorn and try adding this to your Profile `web: gunicorn app:app`. This should fix the problem. If not, as you are using postgresql, it would be helpful if you download the heroku addon for postgresql from [here](https://www.heroku.com/postgres)

### This should fix your problem. If Not, below listed are all the steps for deploying a heroku app. Please check if you followed all the below steps properly and in order.

### For Flask I recommend doing the following things

- Download [heroku cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)
- Start a virtual environment with `python -m venv .` in your project fil
- Activate the virtual environment
- Login to your heroku account in the cli with `heroku login`
- Install [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) `pip install gunicorn`
- In your virtual environment, install the modules again with pip
- Create a requirements.txt with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
- Create "Procfile" with the following info `web: gunicorn app:app`, this will fix the dynamo problem in the log
- Start a empty git repository with `git init`
- Create a appropiate .gitignore, you can find the template [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore)
- Create a new heroku app with `heroku create my-app-flask`
- Add files to heroku git, `git add .`
- As You are using postgresql, it would be helpful if you download the heroku addon for your app Get it [here](https://www.heroku.com/postgres)
- Finally, `git commit -m "Message"` and `git push heroku master`
- This should fix your problem.

Comment: The wsi error is when there is no dynamo. Try using [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) in the Procfile

Comment: so I just did that  I am showing the log now.

Comment: Can you please rephrase that? I didn't get you

Comment: I added the procfile and edited my original question with the new log and more information.

Comment: I also have the heroku postgress add-on

Comment: is there any way you can change the file structure to a simpler one, something like this probaly would be better for gunicorn. I may be wrong, but worth a shot

![image](https://i.imgur.com/vgUE0wq.png)

Comment: It looks like your Procfile is not configured correctly.....

503 error means server error, see [here](https://www.lifewire.com/503-service-unavailable-explained-2622940) Try changing it to a simpler structure. It might work or refer to the gunicorn [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/)